# Query using date datatype in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to do simple select and Update in Oracle 11g using a date where clause and I can't produce the result I expect.

The date field is `datemodified` and currently has values like 12-JUL-14 and of data type date.

I'm doing the following and don't get result:

```
  select *
  from table
  where datemodified = to_date(datemodified, '12-JUL-14')
```

I tried the following and still did not produce result:

```
  select * from table
  where to_date(datemodified, 'DD-MON-YY') = to_date('12-JUL-15',   
  'DD-MON-YY')
```

or

```
  Update table
  set column = 'some value'
  where datemodified = to_date('12-JUL-15', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What century are your stored dates in? You can have problems if whatever is setting that value in the first place is incorrect, e.g. passing 2-digit years with a YYYY mask. (Seeing 2-digit years is often a sign of problems somewhere). Or more likely, do they contain times that are not midnight? Check what you really have with `select to_char(datemodified, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from your_table`, and add some samples to the question.

Comment: Your second and third queries are also using '15' rather than '14', which might not be helping... but as the first one would throw ORA-01821 these might not be what you're actually using anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
select * from table
  where to_char(datemodified, 'dd-MON-yy') = '12-JUL-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle date fields include the time of day.  Also, filtering on function results such as to_char() slows down production.  This method works:

```
where dateModified >= the date you want
and dateModified < the day after the date you want.
```

It's ok to use functions for the values, this for example

```
where dateModified >= trunc(sysdate)
```

or

```
where dateModified >= to_date('12-JUL-15','DD-MON-YY')
```

but not on the field itself